# AngularJS, creating a resource hash

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Trying to take a url and in an AngularJS controller redirect that request to the best place to get the json data. The VideoSearchCtrl is bound to the search form. The url generated is correct for the template so I'm using the controller to redirect it to the place for the json data.

```
GuideControllers.controller('VideoSearchCtrl', ['$scope', 'VideoSearch',
    function($scope, VideoSearch) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(".*/search\\?=(.*)");
        var params = pattern.exec( document.URL )[1];//redirect to videos to execute the search for the data
        $scope.videos = VideoSearch.query({ resource: "videos", action: "search", q: params });
    }
]);
```

This sends /videos/search?q=xyz in to the query. The factory creates the resource:

```
var VideoSearchServices = angular.module('VideoSearchServices', ['ngResource']);

VideoSearchServices.factory('VideoSearch', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource("/:resource/:action:params", {resource: "@resource", action: "@action", params: "@params"}, {
            query: {
                isArray: true,
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
                }
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

But the server gets the url as /videos/search%fq=xyz, not /videos/search?q=xyz and therefore the "show" method is being invoked instead of a custom "search" action.  Obviously there is some escaping somewhere? Or maybe the "?" is also a special pattern the resource factory looks for? Probably obvious to someone used to AngularJS or javascript for that matter.

I have a template for search and the json is retrieved from a different location. Both work but I can't ask for the json with the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do:

```
return $resource("/:resource/:action", {resource: "@resource", action: "@action"}, {
```

Then:

```
$scope.videos = VideoSearch.query({ resource: "videos", action: "search", q: params });
```

The point is `params` are not a part of the url you have to declare to the resource, you just declare `resource` and `action` then you add params which is natural for all routes

Comment: Got it, thanks. Actually you need to exclude "?=" from the 'params' so the regex has been updated in my question. The "?=" will be added by the resource query, just pass the key values pairs.

Comment: Yes params is just an object

Comment: see http://jquery-howto.blogspot.be/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Comment: Sorry, I did +1. I'll figure it out.

Anyway in the case above I removed the "?q=" so did:
    $scope.videos = VideoSearch.query({ resource: "videos",
        action: 'search', q: params });

This seems to imply I'll have to parse more complex prams in my controller and pass them in as separate key-value pairs?

Seems like I'm doing things the wrong way? Is there some way to get that whole param string parsed into a param hash? Something that works for /videos/search?q=xyz&genre=horror&prec=true...

Comment: Ah, the jquery-howto link may be the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a better way to do this with $location from Angular and jQuery's extend that should work with any future params that are added. Will only have to add the new params to the query factory.

```
GuideControllers.controller('VideoSearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'VideoSearch',
   function($scope, $location, VideoSearch) {
      var route = jQuery.extend(
         { resource: "videos", action: 'search' },
         $location.search()
      );
      $scope.videos = VideoSearch.query(route);
   }
]);
```